# Cross Compile OpenCV C++ application ARM

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, cross-compiling

I have read all of the related questions with no success trying anything mentioned anywhere. I am new to cross-compiling and have been working on this for over a week with no progress. So please forgive me if you think I am stupid or have overlooked something.

So I have an application running in C++ that works great on my development computer running Ubuntu 14.04 x64. I am trying to cross compile for my Banana Pro running Lubuntu. Based on the documentation from Lemaker I am supposed to cross compile using "arm-linux-gnueabihf-"

So far the farthest I have been able to get is to :

```
/usr/local/opencv-arm/usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I get this error regardless of what command I run, Here is a list of commands I have tried:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ `arm-linux-gnueabihf-pkg-config arm-opencv --cflags` -Wall  test.cpp -o vis-300 `arm-linux-gnueabihf-pkg-config arm-opencv --libs`

arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ `pkg-config arm-opencv --cflags` -Wall  test.cpp -o vis-300 `pkg-config arm-opencv --libs`

arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc `pkg-config arm-opencv --cflags` -Wall  test.cpp -o vis-300 `pkg-config arm-opencv --libs`

arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ `pkg-config arm-opencv --cflags`  test.cpp -o vis-300 `pkg-config arm-opencv --libs`
```

And there have been many more commands before those with different errors such as:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory

arm-linux-gnueabihf-cpp fatal error too many input files
```

I have tried with just normal arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc/g++, 4.6, 4.7, and 4.8

I have built opencv making small changes for hf using these 2 guides and both produced the same results:
http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Building_OpenCV_for_ARM_Cortex-A8
http://www.ridgesolutions.ie/index.php/2013/05/24/building-cross-compiling-opencv-for-linux-arm/

and not included in either I install it using this command because it will conflict with my current x86_64 install:

```
sudo make install DESTDIR=/usr/local/opencv-arm
```

Also the above pkg-config lines point to my custom pkg config file named arm-opencv.pc

```
# Package Information for pkg-config

prefix=/usr/local/opencv-arm/usr/local
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=
includedir_old=${prefix}/include/opencv
includedir_new=${prefix}/include

Name: OpenCV-arm
Description: Open Source Computer Vision Library
Version: 2.4.10
Libs:  ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_contrib.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_core.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_features2d.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_flann.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_gpu.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_highgui.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_legacy.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_ml.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_nonfree.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_ocl.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_photo.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_stitching.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_superres.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_ts.a ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_video.so ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_videostab.so -lrt -lpthread -lm -ldl
Cflags: -I${includedir_old} -I${includedir_new}
```

Anyways I have tried a lot of stuff short of just installing everything on the board itself and compiling there. Any help is much appreciated and keep in mind I have never successfully cross-compiled before. I always give up and compile on the board.

Comment: Update, I just tried running  `make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-` between the cmake command and the install command. No improvement.

Comment: If Lubuntu is not mandatory, I would try get used to [Buildroot](http://nightly.buildroot.org/manual.html). It provides a lot of packages (OpenCV is of course there too), so you should have no problems with cross-compiling and you always have the same software versions on both your host PC and target. Also take a look at CMake.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. I will check out those 2 things. Just took a glimpse at Buildroot and it sounds really useful. I have compiled OpenCV on the board itself and compiled my application and got it running on there that way. I really wanted to just compile an executable that I can move to other devices. This isn't Ideal and I will still keep plugging away at cross-compile but at least I have a way to get it to work for now.

Comment: Just to make it clear, I still have not found a solution to my question. As stated in my last comment, I have a way around it but it is not the right way to do this and I still need to fix this issue.